# ShortCut - add remined to a specific category based on text

Tags: shortcut, reminders

I have this shortcut where I input a text and add it to my reminders.

I would like to enhance the flow to classify reminders based on a tag i insert into the text. something like the text being

"@tobuy buy milk" --> create a new line "buy milk" into the "tobuy" reminders
"@meeting John" -->create a new line "John" into the "meeting" reminders

Ideas?

[image]